# Conditional user-role in authorization user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

We are using asp.net core in our project and for authorization we use asp.net core identity and entity framwork codefirst approach.we have user and role in my project and i want to my user-role table is conditional based on some attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by user-role table based on some attribute?

Comment: I mean for example i have two companies and one user have diffrent role in two companies. I want to conditional my function based on some attribute for example if i want to delete whole company A , every role and user have been deleted but the user that have role in both company, just in company A deleted not in another company.